# iOS, Can I know if I have an incoming call using CallKit? (NOT VoIP)

Tags: ios, callkit

I don't want to know the Caller ID (because I have the understanding is not possible) BUT, can I know if im receiving a Call?, a normal call on iOS

Comment: According to the documentation, yes. Have you tried it? Please review [ask].

Comment: Only if your app is the current foreground app